# Why is the result different in the Chrome console and sublime? This in JS

Tags: javascript, this, google-chrome-devtools, sublimetext, ecmascript-5

I'm learning about the this identifier and I know that when a function is not called on an object then this refers to the window object in non-strict mode. As a result, I would expect this.bar to log "whatever."

"whatever" is the output when I run my code in the Chrome console.it, but the output is undefined when I run my code using the node build system in sublime.

Why is that the case? Am I right that the result in the Chrome console is correct? When else could I encounter problems like this?

Here's my code

```
function foo() {
    // console.log(this)
    console.log( this.bar );
}

var bar = "whatever";


// --------

foo();              // OUTPUT is "whatever" in the Chrome console and OUTPUT is undefined in Sublime's Node build system.
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does the "this" keyword work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `this` in a function without specifying a different context, it refers to the global object. In Chrome, this will be the `window` object. In Node, this is called `global`. When I say specifying a different context, that would be, for example, using `new` for a constructor, or the `call` and `apply` functions to bind a particular `this`.

The main difference is that when you use `var bar = "whatever";` in Node, the use of `var` is scoping the variable to the module you are writing, not the whole Node process. In Chrome, you are scoping it to the global `window` object. It is the same as leaving out the `var` altogether.

I have added a couple of examples below regarding scope, just to make it a little clearer. Playing around in the Console is a great way to discover things like this.

**Example 1:**
[image: Example 1]
As you can see, calling `test()` has created a globally scope `x` variable, and `this` is found to be referring to the `window` variable.

**Example 2:**
[image: Example 2]
In this example, we constructed a new instance, which creates a new scope. The `x` variable is not scoped globally. The only way to access it is to use the `myInstance` context.

As for your problem, you have two options:

**Option 1 (Recommended):** Since bar is not globally scoped, you don't want to access the global variable using `this`

```
var bar = "whatever";

function foo() {
    console.log(bar);
}
```

**Option 2 (Not Recommended):**
This will set the variable to be in global scope, so you can either use `this` or `global`

```
global.bar = "whatever";

function foo() {
    console.log(this.bar); // console.log(global.bar);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you declare variable in node like this `var bar = 'something'` you declare it not global, but module scoped. You should use `global` object to declare global variable. Something like this:

```
global.bar = 'something';
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure, but I'm assuming it's something to do with the Window object. The function you defined is owned by the Global Window Object. Maybe the Node Build System doesn't have this Global Object.